Do I need to mark my getter/setter and/or class volatile if one of its members is volatile?
I run a complex code on my Teensy board which does beat detection with a microphone and displays some cool LED effects on a bicycle by reacting to them, all in C++ code. But I currently experience a weird behavior where depending on the LED effect that I run, my beat detection does not work as well, and it's consistent for each effect: some work well, some others slow down the detection.
I have a suspicion, although no confirmation, that this comes from how I use my interrupt method to analyze sound.
I have a global variable that I use both in the loop() method and in an interrupt method.
The global variable is defined as:
ApplicationEnvironment env;

The ApplicationEnvironment class is defined as follows (truncated for readability):
class ApplicationEnvironment final : public EffectEnvironment {
 public:
  // Always returns adc0, since we're never using adc1.
  ADC_Module* const GetAdc() { return adc_->adc0; }

  void SetFilteredSignal(int16_t filtered_signal) {
    filtered_signal_ = filtered_signal;
  }
  void SetPeakSignalAmplitude(uint16_t peak_signal_amplitude) {
    unfiltered_signal_peak_amplitude_ = peak_signal_amplitude;
  }
  void SetPeakSignalFilteredAmplitude(uint16_t peak_signal_filtered_amplitude) {
    filtered_signal_peak_amplitude_ = peak_signal_filtered_amplitude;
  }
  uint16_t GetFilteredSignalPeakAmplitude() const override {
    return filtered_signal_peak_amplitude_;
  }

  // Sets whether the beat is currently detected or not.
  void SetBeatActive(bool beat_active) { beat_active_ = beat_active; }

 private:
  // ADC module, to handle ADC properties.
  // Read from ICRSoundProcessing() but does not seem to need 'volatile'.
  ADC* adc_;

  volatile int16_t filtered_signal_;
  // Values below represent the peak seen since their last respective update.
  volatile uint16_t unfiltered_signal_peak_amplitude_;
  // Values below represent the peak seen since their last respective update.
  volatile uint16_t filtered_signal_peak_amplitude_;

  volatile bool beat_active_;
};

In my interrupt method, I call the following methods:
env.GetAdc();
env.GetFilteredSignal()
env.GetFilteredSignalPeakAmplitude();

env.SetFilteredSignal(...);
env.SetPeakSignalAmplitude(...);
env.SetPeakSignalFilteredAmplitude(...);
env.SetBeatActive(...);

I call the setter methods only in the interrupt. I call the getters in both the interrupt and loop().
My questions are as follows:

Do I need to set the env variable as volatile?
More importantly, do I need to set the getter methods as volatile, knowing that they are called within loop()?
Do I need to set the setter methods as volatile, although they are only called from the interrupt?

I believe the adc_ variable does not need to be volatile as it is never changed by the interrupt method.

This looks a bit unusual. How have you mapped filtered_signal_ , unfiltered_signal_peak_amplitude_, filtered_signal_peak_amplitude_ and beat_active_ to hardware addresses?

What do you believe volatile does?  Are you doing that to make the variables thread-safe?

@TedLyngmo: I have not mapped those to any hardware addresses. They are just plain integer values used for other calculations in code. I just need those to be accurate when the interrupt method is called, which is 12,000 times / second.

Ok, so you read from hardware in the ISR and write to the volatiles then?

@DrewDormann: I believe in this case volatile makes sure that when the values are read from loop() and the interrupt method, they always are their latest known value.
Teensy is a bit weird, there is no multi-threading, so none of the variables need thread protection. That said, there is a variable register that can be inaccurate if a value can be updated elsewhere than the method that is currently being executed.
More details: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/variable-scope-qualifiers/volatile/

@TedLyngmo: That is correct!

Ok, then "no" to all questions :)

@TedLyngmo: Just to confirm: even if the getter or setter methods are not marked as volatile, the methods are still going to return, or set, a non-cached value? i.e. the variable register does not impact method return values themselves?
I think my same thought process goes with the env variable: if the variable itself is saved in the variable register, would calling one of its method in the interrupt function return a value from the variable register rather than RAM?

Yes. The read/write from/to the volatile variable is guaranteed to be "non-cached" as you say. It must read/write and not reuse a previously stored value in some register. So, a function that makes a read from a volatile type and returns type will have to perform the read every time the function is called. The env variable shouldn't be volatile. Its adc_ member will not be changed outside the programs control. Making env volatile could possibly make the performance take a hit.

Gotcha. Thank you so much for your insight. This is very useful.
It also means my performance problem is coming from something else... I will continue to investigate!

Indirection by using polymorphism could have some impact on performance. I don't know much about arduinos though so perhaps the overhead is neglectable.

That's fair. This is a Teensy 4.0, so it has a 600 Mhz ARM Cortex-M7, and the method runs at 12,000 Hz. So it should, hopefully, have negligible impact. :P
That said I tried to run it at 24,000 Hz and it could not handle the speed... which makes me a bit worried as I'd assume a 600 Mhz processor would have no issues handling that...
It's really hard to unit test any of this code, so I have to do best guesses to figure out what's going on and it's hard.

Why not try it and see what happens?

@TedLyngmo answered this:

(...) "no" to all questions :)

In more details (see responses above):

Yes. The read/write from/to the volatile variable is guaranteed to be "non-cached" as you say. It must read/write and not reuse a previously stored value in some register. So, a function that makes a read from a volatile type and returns type will have to perform the read every time the function is called. The env variable shouldn't be volatile. Its adc_ member will not be changed outside the programs control. Making env volatile could possibly make the performance take a hit.

